# Floating sliding toggle menu above gmaps

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I am trying to create a floating menu above gmaps without any luck yet. I can do the basic with css but now I've hit a wall trying to use absolute and fixed positioning.

**html**

```
<div id="toggleSettings"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></div>
<div id="toggle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#toggle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#toggleSettings {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#toggleSettings").on('click', function() {
  $("#toggle").toggle("slide");
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16cn9gs9/3/).

The desired behavior is shown in the following images.

#### Closed

[image: Closed]

#### Opened

[image: Opened]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you -
http://jsfiddle.net/16cn9gs9/4/

You have not positioned your #toggle div. So I absolutely positioned it and added two classes for toggling.

CSS :

```
#toggle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -200px;
}
#toggle.slide1 {
  left: 0px;
}

#toggleSettings {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
#toggleSettings.slide2 {
  left: 200px
}
```

JS :

```
$("#toggleSettings").on('click', function() {
  $("#toggle").toggleClass("slide1");
  $("#toggleSettings").toggleClass("slide2");
});
```

You can add transitions for smooth sliding too. Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps thanks. I guess that it's not possible to avoid using width on the sliding div.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it? Anyways, glad I could be of help

Comment: To be able to reuse the same code to place larger elements. I am trying to find a more modern approach using CSS.

Comment: I guess you could get the element's width and translate to -width using jquery...